# Disabling one button in a group of buttons with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

So... basically I'm trying to make a function that reduces the value on the counter and disable a button in the same time, when it's only one button it works perfectly. But when I add more buttons it disable only the first one, the reducing part still working, but disabling not.

```js
let subtract = () => {

  let counter = document.getElementById("counter");

  let button = document.getElementById("button");

  let newScore = Number(counter.innerText) - 1;

  console.log(newScore);

  counter.innerText = newScore;

  counter.classList.remove("new");

  button.setAttribute("disabled", "");
}
```

```html
<div class="new" id="counter">5</div>
<button id="button" onclick="subtract()">exec</button>
<button id="button" onclick="subtract()">exec</button>
```

What can I do to it works as it should??

Tried use "for" with "querySelectorAll" but it still not working

Comment: We cannot possibly debug an image of code. See [ask] and post a [mcve] please

Comment: Please update your question with actual code - consider a snippet to make it easier to both format and reproduce your issue.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code, please update with HTML to reproduce your issue right here.

Comment: Ids are not intended to be applied to more than one element on a page, so getElementById returns only one element. You could use something like getElementsByClassName, which returns a collection of elements, and apply the same class to each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after some time I made it, using event bubbling and other simple functions.
I'll not waste your time and vision, see by yourself here if you're interested:

`[Codepen](https://codepen.io/otaldoallan/pen/xxzQwLo)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).